# Idiomatic way to parse TSV file (ASCII)

Tags: csv, rust

I need to parse files containing tab separated numbers, I also know there will always be only two of them. Since my files can be as heavy as a few gigabytes, I wondered if my current parsing method was correct. It looks like I could make the map faster considering I have a fixed size but I couldn't find how.

```rust
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, BufReader};

type Record = (u32, u32);

fn read(content: &[u8]) -> io::Result<Vec<Record>> {
    Ok(BufReader::new(content)
        .lines()
        .map(|line| {
            let nums: Vec<u32> = line
                .unwrap()
                .split("\t")
                .map(|s| s.parse::<u32>().unwrap())
                .collect();
            (nums[0], nums[1])
        })
        .collect::<Vec<Record>>())
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let content = "1\t1\n\
                    2\t2\n";
    let records = read(content.as_bytes())?;
    assert_eq!(records.len(), 2);
    assert_eq!(records[0], (1, 1));
    assert_eq!(records[1], (2, 2));
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=83051eee9efeea94ee31543fb15f8d21)

Comment: You should use the `csv` crate with a tab separator. You are performing at least one allocation per line plus various allocations / reallocations for the records Vec, csv, especially with Serde integration, should allow more or less zero.

Comment: [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=61063a2955978c090f31d782ce94aa33) seems to make less allocations, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entries are only numbers then we can reduce one inner `Vec` allocation within `map` like so:

```rust
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, BufReader};

type Record = (u32, u32);

fn read(content: &[u8]) -> io::Result<Vec<Record>> {
    return Ok(BufReader::new(content).lines().map(|line| {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        let mut pair = line.split("\t").map(|s|s.parse::<u32>().unwrap());
        (pair.next().unwrap(), pair.next().unwrap())
    }).collect::<Vec<Record>>())
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let content = "1\t1\n\
                    2\t2\n";
    let records = read(content.as_bytes())?;
    assert_eq!(records.len(), 2);
    assert_eq!(records[0], (1, 1));
    assert_eq!(records[1], (2, 2));
    Ok(())
}
```

You may want to add better error handling :)